# ¿Por qué el header se mezcla con el resto de contenido usando position:fixed?

Tags: html, css, html5

Quiero situar el header de forma que se vea siempre cuando se desplace hacia abajo, estoy utilizando html y css solamente:
Este es el código del header, la `<section id="top-stories">` es el conjunto de elementos que quiero que aparezcan después.

```
<header id="main-header"> 
    <h1 id="site-title">Best news boy</h1> 
        <input placeholder="Search..." class="my-input"/>
        <h3 class="">We do not care if it is accurate we care that it is the best</h3>
        <h2>About me section</h2>
        <p>We have spent many years doing what we do and publishing news is what we do best.</p>
</header>
<main>
<section id="top-stories">
...
</section>
```

y el código de css del header es:

```
#main-header {
border-bottom:6px solid #000;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

la cuestión es que cuando añado `position:fixed;`al css de header se mezcla con el contenido del main y aparece un nuevo margin-top de 30px que resulta ser el aplicado en"top-stories"

```
#top-stories {
width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Estoy empezando y no sé si tiene algo que ver el margen de los elementos que preceden a lo que quiero hacer fijo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad `position: fixed` provoca que el elemento sea removido del flujo normal del documento, por lo que deja de ocupar espacio y el resto de elementos va a actuar como si este no existiese. Es por ello por lo que el *"header se mezcla con el contenido del main"*.

Una posible solución es darle una altura fija a tu `<header>` y al `<main>` darle un `margin-top` lo suficientemente alto para que sobrepase la altura del `<header>` y así no verse tapado por este.

Como al hacer **scroll** irremediablemente el contenido de `<main>` va a ser tapado por el `<header>` sería bueno ponerle un `background` para que los textos de ambos elementos no se superponga haciéndolo ilegible.

**Nota:** Debido a la considerable altura que alcanza el `<header>` para apreciar la solución se ha de ejecutar el *snippet* con *Página completa*.

```css
#main-header {
  border-bottom:6px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 233px;
  background-color: white;
}

main {
  margin-top: 263px;
}

#top-stories {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header"> 
  <h1 id="site-title">Best news boy</h1> 
  <input placeholder="Search..." class="my-input"/>
  <h3 class="">We do not care if it is accurate we care that it is the best</h3>
  <h2>About me section</h2>
  <p>We have spent many years doing what we do and publishing news is what we do best.</p>
</header>

<main>
  <section id="top-stories">
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
    
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
    
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
    
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
    
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
    
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
    
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
    
    <p><big>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</big></p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es darle un margin-top al siguiente elemento del header, en este caso el main, de al menos lo mismo que tiene de height el header.